# How To Change List Color in SwiftUI on iOS 16 with Minimum Deployment of iOS 14

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I've developed an app in SwiftUI using a minimum deployment of iOS 14. I have a custom background color which I've always created using a ZStack approach. This has worked well until iOS 16 and Xcode 14.

Historically this worked.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UICollectionView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        
        return ZStack {
            
            Color(.blue)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
                List {
                    Text("Item1")
                    Text("Item2")
                } // List
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            } // VStack
        } // ZStack
    }
}
```

When this is built in iOS 16 in the simulator I see the following. On device the background color is correct. I don't like that the simulator shows the wrong color. It could be a bug in the simulator but this doesn't seem right.

[image]

In iOS 16 the new fix is to place the following modifier on the List.

```
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Full code for iOS 16.

struct ContentView: View {

```
var body: some View {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UICollectionView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    
    return ZStack {
        
        Color(.blue)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            List {
                Text("Item1")
                Text("Item2")
            } // List
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } // VStack
    } // ZStack
}
```

}

This works great. Image below.

[image]

My issue is that with a minimum deployment of iOS 14 the added scrollContentBackground(.hidden) throws an error stating this is only available in iOS 16. Any thoughts on working around this with iOS 16 with a minimum deployment of iOS 14 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This article solves the exact problem you're describing: https://davedelong.com/blog/2021/10/09/simplifying-backwards-compatibility-in-swift/

Comment: Wow! What a great article. This is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the tutorial referenced above and wanted to provide the code below for anyone with the same question.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

public struct Backport<Content> {
    public let content: Content
    
    public init(_ content: Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}

extension View {
    var backport: Backport<Self> { Backport(self) }
}

extension Backport where Content: View {
    @ViewBuilder func scrollContentBackground(_ visibility: Visibility) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            content.scrollContentBackground(visibility)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

In use on List

```
var body: some View {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UICollectionView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    
    return ZStack {
        
        Color(.blue)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            List {
                Text("Item1")
                Text("Item2")
            } // List
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .backport.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } // VStack
    } // ZStack
}
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: You should accept this as your correct answer even though you are the one that post it. ;)